# we are having a domain in AWS, which is currently mapping to loadbalancer of AWS itself but we want to map it to load balancer of Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-load-balancer

how we can include the load balancer of Azure in AWS hosted zones?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b1Hi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Amazon documentation: [Choosing Between Alias and Non-Alias Records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)

You cannot use Azure Public IP DNS name as an alias here. It seems that only Amazon resources could be used as they can be recognized by Amazon platform.

Normally, you just need to directly use the IPv4 address of Azure load balancer. If the public IP is not static, you may try to create a `CNAME` record to its DNS name.